# Firebase: Best way to structure data with multiple URLs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm calling the Pagespeed Insights Lighthouse data for a list of hundreds of URLs and saving the JSON response to Firebase.

I want my front end to be able to call the Firebase and get the last three Lighthouse records for each URL.

How would you structure the data?

My code is below for the database save:

```
firebase.database().ref('/').set({
    url: message,
    jsondata: data,
    created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
  });
```

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: I haven't written the code yet, but it will be something like: `get last three days of Lighthouse audit data for each URL.` I thought about using the URL as the path, but it doesn't like the characters in URLs. Thoughts?